# Elixir Laravel SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: css, json, laravel, gulp

I made some changes to my `gulpfile.js`. Then I received the following syntax error in my terminal after executing the `gulp` command:

```
'version' errored after 657 μs
     SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
        at Object.parse (native)
        at VersionTask.deleteManifestFiles (/var/www/html/work/node_modules/laravel-elixir/dist/tasks/VersionTask.js:114:29)
        at VersionTask.gulpTask (/var/www/html/work/node_modules/laravel-elixir/dist/tasks/VersionTask.js:72:18)
        at VersionTask.run (/var/www/html/work/node_modules/laravel-elixir/dist/tasks/Task.js:139:31)
        at /var/www/html/work/node_modules/laravel-elixir/dist/tasks/GulpBuilder.js:60:37
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at Gulp.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/work/node_modules/laravel-elixir/dist/tasks/GulpBuilder.js:59:54)
        at module.exports (/var/www/html/work/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
        at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/var/www/html/work/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
        at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/var/www/html/work/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
```

Looking in my `public/build/css directory` I noticed all my css versions are incorrect. **How could this happen? How should I fix it?**

gulpfile.js

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vue');


elixir(mix => {
    // for the application, after login
    mix.sass(['styles.scss','imports.scss'])
        .version(['css/styles.css','css/imports.css']);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After opening the `rev-manifest.json` file in the `public/build/` directory, I discovered it was somehow missing `css/imports-xxxxxxx.css`in the json list. I deleted `rev-manifest.json` and entered the command `gulp`. Now after opening `rev-manifest.json` all the css files are listed and the error is gone.